# Binary Search array of NSString wont work?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, binary-search

In the following code test is 0 implying NSOrderedSame and test2 is YES
However, the search function below returns NO.
How can this be? 
The only thing I can think of is that the searchString is an NSString, but the array contains NSCFStrings.

```
int test = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:23] compare: searchString];
BOOL test2 = [((NSString*)[sortedArray objectAtIndex:23]) isEqualToString:searchString];

NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [sortedArray count]);
NSUInteger findIndex = [sortedArray indexOfObject:searchString
                                    inSortedRange:searchRange
                                          options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
                                  usingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                        {
                            return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                        }];
if (findIndex == NSNotFound) {
    return NO;
}
else {
    return YES;
}
```

I read that NSCFStrings are NSStrings so I'm not sure why that would cause this problem...
Anyone have any idea whats goin on?
Thanks!

Comment: You say that `test` is `0` so that implies that `test2` is `YES`. Have you actually verified that `test2` is `YES`?

Comment: What does `[sortedArray indexOfObject:searchString];` return?

Comment: Is `sortedArray` sorted using `compare:`?